# WSO2 BRS Stateful sessions

Tags: wso2, drools, rules

One of the posts on WSO2.com suggests that you can use stateful sessions with Drools in WSO2 BRS. However, all the examples, as far as I can see, use stateless access to a single implicit stateless session.

Can anyone tell me how to configure WSO2 BRS to access more advanced Drools usage and direct service calls to the right sessions, control firing of rules etc ?

Comment: If usage within WSO2 doesn't narrow this question down considerably, this "Can anyone tell..." covers about anything there is in Drools which would result in a 100 page plus answer.

Comment: To be clear, it's really the way WSO2 wraps Drools that I'm asking about. So it's not clear to me how in the WSO2 BRS you can gain more fine control of Drools execution. My best guess is that is in the content of the .rsl file that describes the service, however I can't find a full description of what that file can contain.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that this is being managed through stateful AXIS2 services - so that the Drools session, is in effect, always stateful.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some information even though this question is much older because may helpful to others.

The WSO2 BRS wraps the Drools engine and provide ability to expose set of rules (in several .drl file) and decision tables as axis2 service (lets say rule services).

In BRS you can create stateful and stateless rule session. The stateful sessions are bound to axis2 session (trasport session, soap session, Application session). You can find statful rule session samples in [1]

The service is described in .rsl file. Refer [2] for more information.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/BRS220/Banking+Service

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/BRS220/Creating+and+Deploying+the+Rule+Service